# Declaring and accessing variables in Javascript classes

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ide

I'm learning JavaScript and I ran into an issue concerning class instance attributes. Consider the following code:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    a_plus_b() {
        // My IDE (WebStorm) complains about unresolved variables a and b
        // This also means that autocompletion doesn't work correctly
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
}
let instance = new MyClass(1,1);
let result = instance.a_plus_b();
console.log(result) // shows 2 as expected
```

As the comments in the above chunk of code explain, my IDE complains about unresolved variables `a` and `b` which also means that if I press tab at `instance.` I don't see these variables as attributes of my class instance. What does help is declaring these variables as class attributes right above the constructor with `a;b;`, however it doesn't seem like a sensible solution.

Am I missing something about JS? Is this an IDE bug? Are there any decent workarounds without having to declare these attributes outside the constructor?

Many thanks!

Here is a screenshot from my IDE:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried running your code directly in Node or something? IDEs have a hard time tracking what does and doesn't make sense in JavaScript code (sometimes) because it's so dynamic.

Comment: Public instance fields are available via Babel and in many up-to-date runtime environments. Whether that would make Webstorm happy or not, I can't say.

Comment: It works fine in my IDE, there is no error here.

Comment: Running the code in works fine and it also works in my IDE, what annoys me is the warning as well as not being able to access these attributes.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript or JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using JavaScript